# ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED

Tags: angular, restful-authentication, arangodb

I'm developing an Angular2 application. I am using arangoDB api as the backend to receive the json data. I am using restful api services.

I have added a button in app.component.html to call the function. I have added the codes of service component and app.component below. I am getting the above mentioned error.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { MyHttpserviceService } from './my-httpservice.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl:'app.component.html',
//providers: [MyHttpserviceService]
})

export class AppComponent {
getData: string;
postData: string;

constructor (private http:MyHttpserviceService) {}

client_grid_Get(){

this.http.server_grid_Get().subscribe(
      data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log("finished")
     );
} 
}
```

**my-httpservice.Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class MyHttpserviceService {

constructor(private http:Http) {}

server_grid_Get() {

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var user = "Admin";
var pass = "admin";

//Use Basic authentication
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass));
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credential','true');

return this.http.get("http://190.100.00.000:8000/_db/xxxxx_app/_api/document/wsdl_test/4934434").map(res => res.json());

//request.responseType = 'json'; <--Notice it was removed

 request.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    } else {
        console.warn(request.statusText, request.responseText);
    }
});
request.send();
}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="submit" (click)="client_grid_Get()"> test GET data 
</button>
<p> OUTPUT: {{ getData }} </p>
```

Comment: Check if the authorization token that you are sending to the backend is correct. This error simply means the validation of the user is incorrect.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal hello..,yes I have checked.,the token is correct

Comment: try removing: request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credential','true');

Comment: @AkashAgrawal i tried it now..,the same error exits !!

Comment: Can you see the headers if you inspect the request in a web browser?

Comment: @Alex No i could not see . but this error has been solved. just the user authentication should be done before the return the function.

Comment: @Alex I am getting this error now:  ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal  I am getting this error now: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should call `request.open(URL);` first